# Testing Spring Application with JUnit - Keep data after testclass

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working on a bigger Spring Boot application that has a lot of tests (more like integration tests). My job now is to speed the process of the tests up. I have found, that testData, we need to test the application are set up multiple times in one testrun, if i run multiple test classes. We use something like this to setup the Data in the classes (edit: the Repository and `testDataBuilder` are `@Autowired`):

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    if (Repository.findByShortId("someId") == null) {
        testDataBuilder.createTestData();
    }
}
```

Within the testclass, this works fine. But if my testrun gets to the next class, it seems to drop the data (the data are normally stored in a database, I think within the test the data gets stored in an in - memory database, not sure about that.

I tried multiple things to make this work but nothing did work out in the end:

- building data in an abstract class that every test extends
- working with @commit on some tests
- using a testSuite and trying to create data before all tests like this:

  ```
  @RunWith(Suite.class)
  @SuiteClasses({testClass1.class ...})
  @SpringBootTest
  @ActiveProfiles({ "unit-test" })
  public class testSuite {
  @ClassRule
      public static setupTestData setup = new setupTestData();
  }
  ```

this didn't work, because spring does not run at the time, the `@ClassRule` is run.

What is the best way to setup the testData so not every testClass has to set them up ?

Comment: First question that comes to mind is: Do you really need all the test data in every test? 
And second: Do you really need the whole spring context for every test case? If not you could try reducing the context to only the necessary configurations and beans. Like @WebMvcTest for example.

Comment: Not every tests needs this. There are some tests that need the full context, because we have a complex data modell in the background and some tests need this. The problem is: the test - setup with the data needs about 30 - 45 sec., we have about 8 classes that need the full testdata. Other tests already build data partiall that are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesnt your Test @Configuration map the proper database beans by having H2 inmemory database as a  dependency?

Spring/Springboot caches context automatically without you having to do anything special.

If your @Repository uses the H2 memory, then it will be cached across all Tests cases.

H2 **can** also be configured to write to a file (Instead of memory),if you want it instead of memory.

> ```
> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.
> ```
>
> To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL.
> To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual
> machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;  <-- Writes to a file, and disable closing as long as the VM is alive

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists

Comment: Thank you, this did help a lot. Your idea solved it for me.

Comment: Glad it helped you!